# How do fortran 77 programmers manage without dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, fortran77

I'm starting to learn Fortran, coming from a C++/Matlab/Java background. I realize that some Fortran programmers are still clinging to F77, maybe because they don't like object orientation, namespaces and stuff, and are used to the old syntax.

I understand that you can write a program without OOP. What I don't understand is how you can do without dynamic memory management. There are a thousand examples of cases where you don't know the array sizes in advance - for instance when converting a full matrix to a sparse one.

Of course, modern Fortran offers both "automatic arrays" and "allocatable arrays". But these were not present in 1977. How do the F77 guys manage without these constructs?

Comment: FORTRAN 77 was/is predominantly used for scientific computing, where some chosen initial condition (e.g. a fixed size field) is evolved over an extended period of time, writing out data. There is no user input during the run and you know exactly how big your arrays need to be. Part of the reason Fortran code is often said to be more efficient.

Comment: One approach is to declare a single large array (workspace) and then use integer indices to partition this into various size sections. (I've not worked with f77 so I'm not sure how common this approach would be in reality).

Comment: @Ed Smith Well, there is surely a lot of applications in scientific computing with fixed sizes (numerical linear algebra for instance), but also many with unknown sizes (unstructured meshing, time integration with variable step length, sparse matrices, etc.)

Comment: It is difficult to actually compile with fortran77 as most compilers are F90, F95, or beyond, and they are backwards compatible. So most stable F77 code does not need to be changed, or usually not very much. Even a teenager who started with F77, is going to be >= 40 with F90 being around for ~2.5 decades. It takes about 10 minutes to work out ALLOCATABLE the first time, but it is easy to put it in. If the code works on 32k sections in a streaming fashion, then it is often easier to leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm fully aware that F77 should be buried, and that modern Fortran offers dynamic memory. I'm just curious to how one can ever write code for variable-length arrays without dynamic memory management, and why it took 30 years before it was introduced to the language.

Comment: In a large F77 program I know, it uses C malloc() to allocate a large chunk of memory first (according to the user request from an input file at the startup), then the program uses a stack-like mechanism to access part of that memory. This stack-like access is facilitated by using a common block having only a length-1 array (e.g., common /MEM/ X(1)) and let the subroutine know the offset from the address of X(1) and the (first element of) C-allocated memory, plus the necessary amount requested by each routine. So it is quite awkward but still used in that code as the main memory mechanism :)

Comment: Automatic array was an extension supported in the 80s on several platforms so adopted by f90

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the standard language, the approach was typically to set aside storage in an array that was larger than likely needed, but still within the constraints of the platform running the program, then manually parcel that storage out as required.  The language had features, such as sequence association, storage association, and adjustable arrays, that helped with this parcelling.

Use of language extensions for dynamic memory management was also common.

The capabilities of Fortran 77 and earlier need to be considered in the context of the capabilities of the platforms of the time.

Comment: All valid points. I'm probably "too young" to truly grasp the great revolution of computers and languages of the last 60 years. I guess memory was so expensive in the early days that manual management of variable-length arrays made sense. It also makes sense that malloc-like constructs was provided by language extensions or external procedures, until they were eventually adopted by F90. (Also, I've come to realize that F77 is actually older than the first C standard...)

Comment: Bear in mind as well, that Fortran 90 was [much delayed](https://www.fortran.com/forsaga.html).  A form of it was initially known as Fortran 82!

Comment: I remember we had a machine at work in the early 80s with a 5MB removable hard drive and that machine had 32k of RAM... Man that seemed fast, but almost everything needed to stream through the code. Today's machine at work has 40 cores and 192GB of RAM and a 10TB RAID, and in one vector I have a 200M that I allocate and put onto the stack... And I run multiple instances on many of the cores, and I am usually I/O limited. Everything is literally a million times better/more/bigger.

Comment: Often, horrible games were played with COMMON blocks and EQUIVALENCE statements to work around the lack of dynamic A COMMON block was implemented as a contiguous block of memory so by redefining the variables in the block, one could roll your own dynamic memory pool. EQUIVALENCE statements were an expedient replacement for pointers. The end result was typically a finely tuned morass of unmaintainable vandalism that can only be rivaled by the average C application ;)